# Rails/Sql summing attributes of child element

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

This seems like a simple thing to do but i cant figure it out.

a `scorecard` has a `skills_development`, which has many `training_programs`, which has many `participants`. each participant has an attribute called training_facility_cost i need to take it up an level and find out what the facility cost is for an entire training_program.

so summing all the facility_cost attributes for each child partipant. what is the best way around such a problem. should i do this in a sql query or would using a nested block be more efficient.

something like

```
s.skills_development.training_programs.each do |tp|
  costs = []
  tp.participants.each {|p| costs << p.training_facility_cost}
  costs.inject(:+)
end
```

that doest work though i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

, i think its because all of them have null for the attribute. so its not counting it as zero??

anyone know how to do this fast and simple??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out something like this

```
skills_development.participants.to_a.sum { |p| p.training_facility_cost }
```

Comment: that looks really elegant i like it a lot.
but i still get 

irb(main):124:0> s.skills_development.participants.to_a.sum { |p| p.training_facility_cost }
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: its so strange i thought that was going to work, looking at the db its a decimal data type

Comment: Try to debug what value returning p.training_facility_cost for each participants?

Comment: i think i got it. its because the result is being rounded off two decimal places. i set it to p.training_facility_cost.to_i... dude you get 100 awesome points